# Chrome addon's webRequest.onCompleted does not trigger for requests originated from flash

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to read the content of the requests from the addon. If the page has a flash object, all the requests originated from the flash container does not trigger onComplete method in the addon.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(req){
   console.log(req.url);
},{
  urls: [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
},["responseHeaders"]);
```

I have the required permission in the manifest file and the above code prints all the other requests.

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
```

Chrome dev tools shows all the requests and the above code output is different to that

Further more all those requests are registered in the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` but not in `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.webRequest.onCompleted` is called when request is fully loaded use `chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted` instead